# How to filter a array with Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a simple Livewire component, like the following

```
use Livewire\Component;

class KandidaatList extends Component
{
    public $kandidaten = [];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->kandidaten = '[
        {
          "naam" : "Aad Elias",
          "geslacht": "m",
          "leeftijd": "35",
          "woonplaats": "Groningen",
        },
        {
          "naam" : "Linda de Jong",
          "geslacht": "v",
          "leeftijd": "24",
          "woonplaats": "Mantgum",
        }
      ]';
    }
}
```

**Blade/View**

```
<div>
    @foreach (json_decode($kandidaten) as $kandidaat)
      <div class="pl-14 py-5 border-b border-grey-600 flex justify-around">
        <div>{{$kandidaat->naam}}</div>
        <div>{{$kandidaat->leeftijd}}</div>
        <div>{{$kandidaat->woonplaats}}</div>
        <div class="c-tag c-tag--primary h-5">{{$kandidaat->status}}</div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Now I would like to add a feature so I can filter through the array. For example, if I would type in the name `Aad Elias` that only results with that name show up.

I've generated a component that holds a search query, like the following.

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Search extends Component
{
    public $query;
    
    public function mount()
    {
      $this->query = 'search query';
    }
}
```

And for now, I can output the typed a query in the Blade.

```
<div>
    <input wire:model="query" type="text">
    {{ $query }}
</div>
```

But how do I connect the query I type in this input field with the array from `KandidaatList` to return only results with the searched name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on an array as per your example, I would parse it to a [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) so that you get access to all the helper methods which makes working with arrays much simpler. Then you can leverage some of the `collection` functions to filter your results.

```php
$results = collect(json_decode($kandidaten))->reject(function($item) use ($query) {
    return !preg_match("#^'. $query .'#i', $item->naam);
});
```

What we're doing above is converting the array to a collection and then using the [`reject`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reject) function to return a new collection of results where the name property begins with `$query`.

If you're working with Eloquent models and the database, the first thing I would do is define a `$results` computed property, benefit of this is it gets cached per request so calling `$results` `x` times will not make separate database calls.

```php
public function getResultsProperty()
{
    return $this->search($this->$query);
}
```

Then define a `search` function which is used by the `$results` computed property.

```php
public function search()
{
    return Kandidaten::where('naam', 'like', "{$this->query}%")->get();
}
```

**Note**: I purposefully excluded a `%` from the start of the `like`, but you can make whatever search makes sense for your use case.

Your Livewire component view would remain mostly the same, just replacing the content of your `@foreach`.

```
<div>
    @foreach ($this->results as $kandidaat)
      <div class="pl-14 py-5 border-b border-grey-600 flex justify-around">
        <div>{{$kandidaat->naam}}</div>
        <div>{{$kandidaat->leeftijd}}</div>
        <div>{{$kandidaat->woonplaats}}</div>
        <div class="c-tag c-tag--primary h-5">{{$kandidaat->status}}</div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```